# how to limit CPU for vmmem process

Tags: wsl-2, rancher

In windows 10 machine I have installed Rancher Desktop which requires WSL2.

Whenever I started the Rancher Desktop, the `vmmem` process started high CPU utilization and  going till 100%. I am seeing article to limit the memory using wslconfig file  (`c:\Users\damie\.wslconfig`), but only the memory.

Is there way to limit CPU as well?

```
[wsl2]
memory=4GB
```

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "processors" which can be used to set how many cores the WSL2 has available. For example:

```
[wsl2] 
memory=16000MB    #Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 900MB 
processors=8    #Makes the WSL 2 VM use one virtual processors
```

Here's the documentation from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the processors property in `.wslconfig` as Mikael Koskinen points out, e.g.

```
[wsl2] 
memory=6GB
processors=2
```

The Microsoft documentation shows a sample `.wslconfig` with a comment that `processors` refers to virtual processors. However, I am seeing in my experimentation that it actually corresponds to cores. For example, here I have set `processors=2` in .wslconfig and it appears that 2 cores (4 logical processors), the ones shown in the lower four panes, share the same pattern.

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: For newcomers, .wslconfig file is found (or can manually be created) in C:\Users\USERNAME directory